# How to use Vue.util.extend in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

**How does one use Vue.util.extend in a Vue Component?**

I need to copy data (with no references) from a prop and using **Vue.util.extend({}, this.propData)** was suggested, but there's no instructions on how to use that.

What exactly do I have to import to get the helper function working?

example-component.vue

```
<script>
import Vue ...???

export default {

  props: {
    propData: Array
  }

  data() {
    return() {
      localPropData: Vue.util.extend({}, this.propData)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Even links to some form of documentation on this would be helpful. For now I decided to just use JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.propData)) which works perfectly fine.

Using Vue 3 via Laravel 8

Comment: Have you tried using spread syntax? `localPropData: [...this.propData]`

Comment: I can't find much info on `Vue.util.extend`, looks like it might be from Vue v1